# How to Present error's using v-for and vee-validate

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

Quick question, I'm probably missing something.
I have some validations using vee-validate, I'm trying to present an error's after iterating over an object, but I managed to present error only on the last input field.

Here's my code:

```
<ValidationProvider name="integrationParams[key]" rules="required" v-slot="{ errors }" v-for="(param, key, index) in integrationParams" :key="key">
    <label class="inputLabel" :for="key">Please fill in {{ key }} param</label> <span class="redStar">*</span>
    <input v-model="integrationParams[key]" :id="key">
    <span class="invalid-feedback">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
</ValidationProvider>
```

For example I have 5 fields and I managed to present an error only on the last field. what am I missing here?

Comment: try naming the input `name="namedField"` then `{{ errors.namedField }}`

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it's not working

Comment: Any other suggestion ??